# Generic field type in C# entity

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class of several fields:

```
class Entity{
   public int field1 {get; set;}
   public int field2 {get; set;}
   public int field3 {get; set;}
}
```

However, I want to be able to reuse this class with the other types: string or bool maybe.
But the compiler does not like if I replace public int field1 {get; set;} with public T field1 {get; set;}
What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: `class Entity<T> { ... }`

Comment: @J.Doe Please accept one of anwsers if any of them was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need a generic parameter on your type, like this:

```
class Entity<T> {
   public T field1 {get; set;}
   public T field2 {get; set;}
   public T field3 {get; set;}
}
```

You can then re-use this like so:

```
class EntityOfInt : Entity<int> {
   ///field1 is an int
   ///field2 is an int
   ///field3 is an int
}
```

Comment: Alex, so in your example EntityOfInt is "empty" - it has not overridden fields, right?

Comment: No, it inherits properties from its base class

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4 and above you can use dynamic

```
class Entity {
   public dynamic field1 {get; set;}
   public dynamic field2 {get; set;}
   public dynamic field3 {get; set;}
}
```

possible overide

```
class Foo : Entity {
public new string field1 {get; set;}
public new int field2 {get; set;}
//field3 is still dynamic
}
```

This way you can still do boxing and unboxing for both types, and have your fields exposed. If not overrwriten, they will stay dynamic. So you can have simple class syntax and possibility for multiple unconstrained templates within one class.

class above using generic template

```
class Entity<T1,T2,T3> 
     where T3: new()
{
   public T1 field1 {get; set;}
   public T2 field2 {get; set;}
   public T3 field3 {get; set;}
}
```

as you can see this can quickly get out of hand,

but remember, this is not type safe as method with `class Entity<T>`, because dynamic fields will accept all types, and override previously used. And you will have to unbox it every time you want to use it as object.

For more information see MSDN

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: I was also thinking of dynamic but I am not sure if it's a good way to use it in a base class and then in the derived one use string, int, etc

Comment: @J.Doe you can go like this: Create Entity dynamic and for inheritance `public new string field1 {get;set};` Operator new will allow you to put any type in there, and it will still allow boxing and unboxing. This way, you will hide (internaly) your Entity::field1 but will remain compilable with it. But as mentioned above. You have to be cerfull with dynamic.

Comment: is there a way to avoid using dynamic but still being able to use any time in the derived class?

Comment: yes, you can use `object`, instead of `dynamic`, but this might result with exceptions since you won't be able to make runtime changes to the type. Once field is lets say a int type, you would not be able to put there string, like you can with dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple generic types:

```
public class Entity<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{
  public virtual T1 Field1 {get;set;}
  public T2 Field2 { get; set; }
  public T3 Field3 { get; set; }
  public T4 Field4 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Entity<int, string, bool, int>
{
    public override int Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it looks interesting, but what about the derived class? it will have no overridden fields, right?

Comment: You can make the members virtual, see Field1.